# Using Multidimensional Arrays to Keep Track of Indices in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project where I need to sort an array from least to greatest, but save the values of the indices. For example, with the array {2, 7, 8, 1, 3}, the sorted indices would be {3, 0, 4, 1, 2}. I thought that I could use a two dimensional array to accomplish this; I would add the index to each component, sort the array, then retrieve the original index from the second element. It hasn't been working for me as well as I hoped though, I have my current code below and it keeps giving me a segmentation fault. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'm assuming its something in my for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 7;

int main()
{
  int intArray[SIZE] = {5, 3, 32, -1, 1, 104, 53};
  int i, j, k, l = 0;
  int temp[SIZE][2];

  //fills multidimensional array temp with data from intArray or index #
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      switch (j)
    {
    case '0':
      temp[i][j] = *intArray;
      break;
    case '1':
      temp[i][j] = i;
      break;
      }
    }
  } 

  sort(intArray, intArray + SIZE);

  //prints each component of temp individually
  cout << "Sorted Array looks like this." << endl;
  for (k = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for (l = 0; j < 2; i++){
      cout << &temp[k][l] << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on how you need to keep track of your data... I'd use a `std::vector` of `std::pair` (`std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>>`) where the first value in the pair was the array value, and the second is the array index. Using that, you should be able to use an STL sorting algorithm to sort your vector and you're done.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mentioned using your code: http://ideone.com/hQZ7zk

Answer (score 1):

The following loop is much simpler and does what it should:

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    temp[i][0] = intArray[i];
    temp[i][1] = i;
}
```

One error in your code is the line

```
temp[i][j] = *intArray;
```

This always assigns the 1st element of `intArray`.

The thing that causes the segmentation fault is probably the & in the output statement, just remove it.

Aside from that, I agree with the recommendation in the comment by RyanP.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::map. The code will be the easiest. Test on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int>arr = {{5,0}, {3,1}, {32,2}, {-1,3}, {1,4}, {104,5}, {53,6}};
    for(auto&x:arr) std::cout << x.first << " - > " << x.second << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the original array has duplicate elements. The keys of `std::map` have to be unique.

Comment: @Frank Puffer In task does not say anything about the duplicates. But this is not important. The main thing - the proposal to use the <map>. To work with duplicates elementary replace std::map on std::multimap.

Comment: Yes. I agree. And std::map is a container for sorted pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using what Frank Puffer said and chose to use a simple bubble sort instead of using any of the built in functions. Here is a link to what my final program looked like http://ideone.com/cpEgGA

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 7;

int main()
{
  int intArray[SIZE] = {5, 3, 32, -1, 1, 104, 53};
  int i, j, k, l, m = 0;
  int temp2[SIZE][2];
  int indices[SIZE] = {};

  for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    temp2[i][0] = intArray[i];
    temp2[i][1] = i;
  }

  cout << "Unsorted Array looks like this." << endl;
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){
    cout << temp2[j][0];
    cout << " : ";
    cout << temp2[j][1] << endl;
  }

  for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < SIZE-1-k; j++)
    {
      if(temp2[j+1][0] < temp2[j][0])
        {
          l = temp2[j][0];
          temp2[j][0] = temp2[j+1][0];
          temp2[j+1][0] = l;
          l = temp2[j][1];
          temp2[j][1] = temp2[j+1][1];
          temp2[j+1][1] = l;
        }
    }
    }

  cout << "Sorted Array looks like this." << endl;
  for (m = 0; m < SIZE; m++)
    {
      cout << temp2[m][0];
      cout << " : ";
      cout << temp2[m][1] << endl;
    }

  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    indices[i] = temp2[i][1];
  }

  cout << "Indices of Sorted Array look like this." << endl;
  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    cout << indices[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```